# access to request querystring in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller

i have a actionLink in my view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("go", "ShowDetails", "ShowNews", new { id = 2 },null);
```

and in my RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name:"newMap",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "shownews", action = "showdetails", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

when click on this actionLink and request query string by this cod in my controller

```
public ActionResult ShowDetails()
    {
        int id;
        if (!int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out id))
        {
            id = 1;
        }

        var data = new DatabaseContext();
        var news = data.newsInfo.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(news);
    }
```

but this request return to me always return 1 (i send 2 by actionLink)
but when i go to address :

```
localhost/ShowNews/ShowDetails?id=2
```

request.querystring pars the 2 value(this is true)
what is the problem?

Comment: what language is this and what does this logically mean: `Where(x => x.ID == id)`?

Comment: c#-
this section of cod 'Where(x => x.ID == id)' don not important
i want to access to query string

Comment: maybe `Request.QueryString("id")`?

Comment: this syntax work in VB.Net
in C# is Request.QueryString["id"]

Comment: Did you log the value of `Request.QueryString["id"]` in `ShowDetails()`?

Comment: i find my problem
i access to querystring by add argoment in 
 public ActionResult ShowDetails(string id)